# Submitting data from a div to database, which(div) is getting a data after appending a id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I know its very complex but all I am trying to do is make a tag system. I am getting data from database with an ajax call using the "@" initial . I am able to do everything, even the tags are being created but I am unable to fetch those tags and submit them in the database under table tags.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
        ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        var start=/@/ig; // @ Match
        var word=/@(\w+)/ig; //@abc Match

        $("#text").live("keyup",function()
        {
        var content=$(this).text(); //Content Box Data
        var go= content.match(start); //Content Matching @
        var name= content.match(word); //Content Matching @abc
        var dataString = 'searchword='+ name;
        //If @ available
        if(go.length>0)
        {
        $("#msgbox").slideDown('show');
        $("#display").slideUp('show');
        $("#msgbox").html("Type the name of someone or something...");
        //if @abc avalable
        if(name.length>0)
        {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "boxsearch.php", // Database name search
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
        $("#msgbox").hide();
        $("#display").html(data).show();
        }
        });
        }
        }
        return false();
        });

        //Adding result name to content box.
        $(".addname").live("click",function()
        {
        var username=$(this).attr('title');
        var old=$("#contentbox").html();
        var content=old.replace(word," "); //replacing @abc to (" ") space
        $("#contentbox").html(content);
        var E="<a class=red contenteditable='false' href='#' >"+username+"</a>";
        $("#contentbox").append(E);
        $("#display").hide();
        $("#msgbox").hide();
        });
          });
        </script>

         // Inserting data to database using ajax
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
        libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function()
        {
        var contentbox = $("#contentbox").val();
        var dataString = 'contentbox='+ contentbox;
        if(contentbox.length < 1)
        {
        alert('It seems you havnot entered anything.');
         }
         else
        {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert-tag.php",
        clearForm: true,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html){
        $("ol#update-status").append(html);
        $("ol#update-status li:last").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#flash").hide();
        document.getElementById("text").value = "";  
        }
        });
        }return false;
        }); });
        </script>
        //HTML Code
        <div id="container">
        <div id="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
        <div id='display'>
        </div>
        <div id="msgbox">
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div id="contentbox" >
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="submit">

        </div>
```

Comment: The `data` option in jquery ajax has to hold variables like this: `data: {dataString: dataString },`

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers Actually, according to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) `data` can be an object, a string, or an array.

Comment: `var contentbox = $("#contentbox").val();` may need to be `var contentbox = $("#contentbox").text();`

Comment: @KoenHoeijmakers I dont think so thats the issue, I have worked with same format and ajax work awesome, here in this case the real issue is that I can get hold of the data coming in #contentbox which I am trying to send to other table in database

Comment: @PatrickQ I did put the HTML code below, did you not see that ?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickQ it worked. It worked with .text() instead of .val(). But will you please explain me the difference between and what exactly was wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#contentbox")` is not an `input` element, and therefore you cannot call [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on it.  Use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead.

Replace

`var contentbox = $("#contentbox").val();`

with

`var contentbox = $("#contentbox").text();`

In fact, you are already doing it this way elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for that, its working but in the database, I am getting this whole string # <a class=red contenteditable='false' href='#' >"+username+"</a> #.  I guess what Patriq said is best, I just replaced .val with .text and hurray, its getting done.

Comment: Load the edit.  I mistakenly pasted `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the accepted solution.